# How to load angular states dynamically using user service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs 1.2.23 and I want to create a provider that will load the states based on some result returned by a service. Consider below code sample-

```js
app.provider("myStateProvider", function ($stateProvider, CustomService) {

   CustomService.getMenus({}, {}).$promise.then(function (menu) {
     $stateProvider.state(menu);
   });

});
```

It throws me below error-
Unknown provider: CustomServiceProvider

Any suggestions...

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your app `app.provider("CustomService",.....` ?

Comment: Have a service like app.service('CustomService', function ($resource) {});

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

When you inject a `provider` to your application, it's called the **configuration phase** of the application. During this phase, services aren't accessible because they haven't been created yet. (Reference https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

When you inject `service`, `factory`, `controller` - It's injected in the **run** block - there you can inject a service (such as `CustomService`), but NOT a provider - Which you didn't injected, so it's OK (Reference https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

You can create a provider to your `CustomService` service:

```
app.provider("CustomService", function () {
     ... LOGIC GOES HERE (PUT GENERAL LOGIC RELATED TO THE SETUP PHASE OF THE SERVICE)
});
```

And you'll be able to inject it into `myStateProvider` later:

```
app.provider("myStateProvider", function ($stateProvider, CustomServiceProvider) { ...  });
```

Last thing: Don't add **Provider** to the provider name, just do:

```
app.provider("myState", function ($stateProvider) {
});
```

WHY? Because if you need to inject it, you'll need to inject `myStateProviderProvider` (Angular adds the "Provider" automatically)

Comment: Hi Alon, thanks for your explanation but my problem is, I need some data at the configuration stage with the help of **$resource**. If I can use `app.provider("CustomService", function ($resource) {
     ... LOGIC GOES HERE
});` I'll be fine. So, the basic problem is, loading some data using a rest service at angular configuration stage.

Comment: You won't be able to inject `$resource` into a `provider` because it's the configuration phase, you can inject `$resourceProvider` however (Not sure however if this would help). Note that you can resolve dependencies before you enter a specific state in your app (Read about **route resolve** here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: And here is a full tutorial http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx